# How to prefix int data type value with leading zeroes?

Tags: sql, database-design

would it be possible to set an int value to begin with a zero? example would be like an ID number which would be `0020192` but it only saves it as `20192`, i guess it would be possible to set it as a string related type but if possible let it remain as Int.

the 00 would be required cause the first 3 digits(002) denote an employee work section while the last 4 would be the employee's actual number(0192, the 192nd employee)

Comment: That's a display problem. Don't mess with what's stored in the database so it can conform to some arbitrary "prettiness" standard. A number is a number. Do the zero-padding in the client.

Comment: @MarcB: "A number is a number" except when it isn't. A zip code may look like a number but it isn't, it is a string that happens to contain digits. Similar things apply to various other codes that look numberish.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Is this ID actually a number or is there an external specification that says that IDs are strings of eight digits? There is a fair bit of difference between those two cases.

Comment: actually it would be a seven digit id. 0090001, the first three digits (009) would identify the workstation of an employee while the last 4 digits(0014) would be his actual employee id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your comment you say this:

> actually it would be a seven digit id. 0090001, the first three digits (009) would identify the workstation of an employee while the last 4 digits(0014) would be his actual employee id.

That says that your IDs aren't actually numbers at all, they're strings with a specific internal structure:

1. Seven characters long.
2. All characters are digits.
3. The first three characters identify a workstation.
4. The last four characters identify an employee.

That's a string that just happens to look like a number. You should use a `char(7)` for this and add a CHECK constraint to enforce the internal format (or as much of it as you can get away with).

I also don't see much chance of doing any arithmetic or other number-ish things with these IDs, mostly because they are not, in fact, numbers.

A happy side effect of using `char(7)` for this is that your application should treat the IDs as strings and you won't have to worry about something getting confused and thinking that `0112222` is an octal number.

If possible you should use two separate string columns:

1. A `char(3)` for the workstation ID.
2. And a `char(4)` for the employee ID.

If you have these two objects elsewhere in your database using numeric IDs then use two numbers here as well and add foreign keys to constraint your data.

**Executive summary**: Your IDs are not numbers so don't try to store them as numbers, they're strings that look like numbers and should be stored and manipulated as strings.

Comment: thanks. i have thought about setting them as char but not about separating them into 2 columns. thanks for the tip

Comment: @JLawrence: You're usually better off breaking your data down into the smallest logical pieces and then let the database deal with it, don't try to outsmart your database, you'll usually just make your life harder.

Answer (score 2):

just try this code

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('0000000', 201920),8) AS ID_Number
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7215e/1

Comment: This one is for MySQL. other answer mentioned below is for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

only a display issue.

if your IDNO(autoincrement/int) in the database is 201 and you want it to be displayed to a 10 character long format e.g. 0000000201

should be like this.

```
select rtrim(replicate('0',abs(len(IDNO)-10)) + CAST(IDNO as varchar)) from IDMaster
```

just modify 10 on your preferred length of display. 
e.g. 2 , so abs(len(IDNO)-2)

cheers.